# How can I hide or remove a sub-menu inside dropdown menu? I am new to python django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

So, I found the below Django source code file on the internet.

**generic_subnavigation.html**

```
{% load common_tags %}
{% load navigation_tags %}

{% if link|common_get_type == "<class 'mayan.apps.navigation.classes.Menu'>" %}
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            {% if link.icon %}{{ link.icon.render }}{% endif %}
            {{ link.label }}
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% navigation_resolve_menu name=link.name as sub_menus_results %}
            {% for sub_menu_results in sub_menus_results %}
                {% for link_group in sub_menu_results.link_groups %}
                    {% with '' as li_class_active %}
                    {% with link_group.links as object_navigation_links %}
                        {% include 'navigation/generic_navigation.html' %}
                    {% endwith %}
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% else %}
    {% if as_li %}
        <li class="{% if link.active and li_class_active %}{{ li_class_active }}{% endif %}">
    {% endif %}
        {% include link_template|default:'navigation/generic_link_instance.html' %}
    {% if as_li %}
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

The code renders a webpage with sub-menus shown in the picture below;

[image: render sub-menu]

How do I remove the "setup and tools" menu in the sub-menus shown in the picture? At least comment on it out.

**generic_link_instances.html**

```
 {% if link.separator %}
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
{% elif link.text_span %}
    <li class="text-center link-text-span {{ link.html_extra_classes }}" >{{ link.text }}</li>
{% else %}
    {% if link.disabled %}
        <a class="{{ link.html_extra_classes }} {% if link_classes %}{{ link_classes }} {% else %}btn {% if 'dangerous' in link.tags %}btn-danger{% else %}btn-primary{% endif %} btn-xs{% endif %} {% if link.active %}{{ link_class_active }}{% endif %} {% if 'new_window' in link.tags %}new_window{% endif %} disabled" disabled='disabled' style="cursor: default;" href="#">{% if link.icon %}{{ link.icon.render }}{% endif %} {{ link.text }}{% if link.error %} - {{ link.error }}{% endif %}</a>
    {% else %}
        <a
            class="{{ link.html_extra_classes }} {% if link_classes %}{{ link_classes }} {% else %}btn {% if 'dangerous' in link.tags %}btn-danger{% else %}btn-primary{% endif %} btn-xs{% endif %} {% if link.active %}{{ link_class_active }}{% endif %} {% if 'new_window' in link.tags %}new_window{% endif %}"
            {% for key,value in link.html_data.items %}
                data-{{ key }}={{ value }}
            {% endfor %}

        {% if link.html_extra_attributes %}{{ link.html_extra_attributes }}{% endif %}
        {% if link.url %}href="{{ link.url }}"{% endif %}
        >{% if link.icon and not hide_icon %}{{ link.icon.render }}{% endif %}
        {{ link.text|default:'' }}{% if link.badge_text %}&nbsp;<span class="badge">{{ link.badge_text }}</span>
        {% endif %}{% if link.error %} - {{ link.error }}{% endif %}
        </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

**generic_navigation.html**

```
{% load i18n %}

{% for link in object_navigation_links %}
    {% include 'navigation/generic_subnavigation.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

**action_dropdown.html**

```
{% load i18n %}

{% load common_tags %}

<button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="{{ action_dropdown_classes|default:"btn btn-default btn-danger"}} btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
    {% if action_dropdown_label %}
        {{ action_dropdown_label }}
    {% else %}
        {% trans 'Actions' %}
    {% endif %}
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">{% trans 'Toggle Dropdown' %}</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    {% for menus_link_result in action_menus_link_results %}
        {% if not action_menu_disable_labels and action_menus_link_results|length > 1 %}
            <li class="dropdown-header"><strong>{{ menus_link_result.menu.label }}</strong></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for link_group in menus_link_result.link_groups %}
            {% if navigation_object_list %}

                {% ifchanged link_group.object %}
                {% common_get_object_verbose_name obj=link_group.object as link_group_object_verbose_name %}
                    {% if link_group_object_verbose_name %}<li class="dropdown-header">{{ link_group_object_verbose_name }}</li>{% endif %}
                {% endifchanged %}
            {% endif %}

            {% with link_group.links as object_navigation_links %}
            {% with 'true' as as_li %}
            {% with 'true' as hide_active_anchor %}
            {% with 'btn btn-sm navigation-btn-dropdown' as link_classes %}
                {% include 'navigation/generic_navigation.html' %}
            {% endwith %}
            {% endwith %}
            {% endwith %}
            {% endwith %}

            {% if not forloop.last and link_group %}
                <li class="divider"></li>
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
        {% if not forloop.last and menus_link_result %}
            <li class="divider"></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Mayan`>`Apps`>`Common`>`Apps.py`
(see the screenshot) and remove what you need to.

[image: apps.py]